# How to check if a constructor has a specific parameter in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I have a class named Enemy that has three constructors. It has a default, one with stats and an item, and one with just stats. What I want to accomplish is to make a function that can detect whether or not an enemy has an item. I suppose I could easily make another parameter that contains an integer value of the number of items they have, but I would really like to be able to just check for the item parameter so that I don't need to make another constructor parameter.

Alternatively,  I think I could also just put in a parameter in my item class that is either a 1 or 0 and that would allow a check to determine if an item is present or not.

The reason I want to be able to detect an item is so that if the enemy does have one, a sequence happens where it tells you the item and then gives you the option to pick it up or not.

Comment: Can you post your relevant code?

Comment: Not sure why you would even want to do this, instead of just having a member that indicates whether or not an instance of Enemy has an item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task is maybe not really complex as long as you can always omit specifying parameter with default value (e.g. Nothing). The parameter that we can omit should be either the last one or the previous to omitted. So, what you've described is relatively easy fits in:

```
class Stats
{
    public:
      // some stat methods and data
};


enum Item
{
   Nothing,
   Something1,
   Something2,
   Something3
};


class A
{
   explicit A(Item item = Nothing);
   A(const Stats& stats, Item item = Nothing);
};


A::A(Item item)
{
   // in both constructors just recognize if the item is Nothing
   if (item == Nothing)
   {
      // default, no item
   }
   else
   {
      // deal with an item
   }
}
```

So, your client code will be able to do:

```
// we imply item != Nothing here
A one;                 // default
A two(item);           // with an item
A three(stats);        // with stats
A four(stats, item);   // with stats and an item
```

Of course you should specify an item and stats somehow.